# EFI Boot loader problem for dualboot system with windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I succesfully installed ubuntu 14.04 manually alongside windows 8.1 on my Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga.

However I did not manage to fix the booting process. So here is what I tried so far:

- using "efibootmgr" I am able to find an boot entry which is "ubuntu"
- using "efibootmgr -n " and the appropriate boot entry for ubuntu restarting leads to the GRUB2 menu where I can select my ubuntu installation. However this works only once.
- using "efibootmgr -o " to change the boot order changes the order according, however the system directly boots windows and when checking the boot order the entries are as before the changes
- using "efibootmgr " to deactivate the windows boot loader entry does also not work
- changing the boot path with "bcdedit" from within windows did not change anything

My guess is now that the firmware is constantly overwriting the boot order if windows boot loader is not the first entry.

I hope that someone has some idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar question for dual boot system. Someone gave some advice. Probably it also helps you. In general, there is no straightforward solution for stopping Windows from re-writing the boot order. But, modifying bootmgfw.efi may help. I have not tried it though.

[Ubuntu 14.04 installed alongside with Windows 8.1 but the system boot directly to Windows once I logged into Windows and restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511109/ubuntu-14-04-installed-alongside-with-windows-8-1-but-the-system-boot-directly-t)